# Как поднять определенную базу в начало в phpmyadmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

В phpmyadmin имеются чуть больше сотни баз данных. Постоянно обращаюсь только к одной базе (другие требуются крайне редко). Сами базы выстроены по алфавиту и нужная база находится около середины списка. Есть ли какой способ поднять определенную базу в списке в самый верх, т.е. поставить ее первой, что постоянно не искать ее глазами и не пользоваться фильтрацией?

Comment: Перейдите в саму базу, скопируйте ссылку из адресной строки и выведите ярлык на раб. стол указав скопированную ссылку.

Comment: формально, это можно сделать например задав список доступных баз в [`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['only_db']`](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_only_db)

Comment: Kvilios, нет, это не вариант. Точнее вариант, но не в моем случае, т.к. браузер у меня не закрывается месяцами и постоянно в нем висит вкладка с открытым phpmyadmin. Пока авторизация в нем не слетела, то все нормально - база открыта, я с ней работаю. Но как только авторизация слетела, мне приходится авторизовываться заново, и по умолчанию в левой части открывается общий список баз, среди которых мне приходится искать нужную мне. Увеличивать время жизни сессии не вариант в целях безопасности.

Comment: `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['favorite']` еще можно таблицу из этой БД закрепить вверху где то, и потом из таблицы как то может быть переходить к базе

Comment: teran, ну это не очень хорошо, т.к. остальные базы иногда тоже требуются...

Comment: teran, $cfg['Servers'][$i]['favorite'] - уже какой-то вариант, т.к. работаю, как правило, с двумя-тремя таблицами. А нет чего-то такого же, но не для таблицы, а для БД?

Comment: @Инопланетныйгость дак наверное можно и не статикой вбивать, а получить список баз, и пересортить.

Comment: если у вас свой личный пхп админ, то встройте в js скрипт который будет искать в дереве нужную базу и просто переставлять ее вверх. не знаю, там слева дерево без каждый раз строится или нет.

Comment: teran, js - тоже вариант, может даже самый предпочтительный из всех предложенных вариантов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Благодаря **teran** (в комментариях), сделал JQuery-вставку в файл /js/ajax.js в начало функции "resetFavicon()" следующего содержания:

```
    if ($('#pma_navigation_tree div ul li a').filter(function(){
            return $(this).attr('href').match(/db_structure.*db=имя_базы.*/);
    }).parent().index() != 0) {
            $('#pma_navigation_tree div ul li a').filter(function(){
                    return $(this).attr('href').match(/db_structure.*db=имя_базы.*/);
            }).parent().prependTo('#pma_navigation_tree div ul');
    }
```

где **имя_базы** - имя базы данных, которую необходимо поднять вверх.

**teran** - спасибо!

Comment: что-то сложно у вас. как-то так не получится? `$("#pma_navigation_tree a[href$=dbname]").parent().prependTo("#pma_navigation_tree ul")` ?

Comment: в общем фильтрацию можно заменить  селектором с атрибутом. и не взывать эту фильтрацию 2 раза

Comment: ну да, div ul li можно было опустить, здесь без вопросов. Сделал на всякий случай, мало ли еще где в коде встречается такая ссылка, чтобы уж точно найти необходимый li. А два раза сделано для того, что т.к. я вставил в функцию, которая (видимо) вызывается при щелчке практически по любой ссылке в правой части phpmyadmin (т.е. не в дереве баз данных), то происходит постоянное добавление нужной базы в первую позицию. И получается несколько одинаковых записей одной базы. А так она перемещается в первую позицию только если она еще не в первой позиции.

Comment: ну я про замену `.filter` на `a[href$=...]` больше писал